# Trouble with Rails and BCrypt has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, controller, bcrypt

I'm pretty new to Rails, so I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm having a really rough time getting bcrypt's `has_secure_password` to work.

I'm attempting to register users via an axios AJAX call from a React frontend. The data is being passed in correctly and I'm not having any CORS issues, since when I remove the `has_secure_password` line (and replace `:password` with `:password_digest` in all the applicable places), the user is entered into the database -- just without an encrypted password. I've sorted through a bunch of the previous questions & answers on `has_secure_password` & nothing seems to be working.

Here's what the server spits out when I try to create the new user:

```
1| Started POST "/api/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-19 20:51:19 -0500
2| Processing by Api::UsersController#create as HTML
3|   Parameters: {"name"=>"test", "username"=>"test25", "email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "username"=>"test25", "email"=>"test@test.com"}}
4|    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
5|    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
6| Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

(Despite the optimism of that last line, the user isn't entered into the database. Also, note the missing `password` information in the second half of line 3.)

Here's my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end
```

I have also tried using `ActiveRecord::Base` in the place of `ApplicationRecord` and adding `include ActiveModel::SecurePassword` in there as well, neither of which did anything.

Here's my create user controller (it's sort of a mess, since I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing):

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render json: { user: user }
  else
    render json: {error: "there was an error"}
  end
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password)
end
```

The AJAX call sends the password as `password: [password here]` and I have a `:password_digest` column in my table. Any help diagnosing the error would be very appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

**Edited to add**:

Creating the user in the ruby console works fine

Comment: Try going to the Rails Console and creating a new user there with user = User.create. When it fails, type user.errors.full_messages to see where it's failing.

Comment: @Dithanial Creating it in the rails console worked no problem, actually. Still doesn't work with the AJAX call. I updated the error response from the controller with `user.errors.full_messages` instead of 'there was an error' and got "Password can't be blank".

Comment: does BCrypt require a password confirmation?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss from what I can tell it'll work without one, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html ... the example I'm working from also didn't have the confirmation field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I don't love this solution, but this ended up working:

Adding the user without the `user_params` definition worked.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def create
      user = User.new({name: params[:name], username: params[:username], password: params[:password], email: params[:email]})
      if user.save
        render json: { user: user }
      else
        render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages}
      end
    end

  end
```

I would still like to know *why* this happened, as it seems like very odd & counterintuitive behavior and I imagine that having the `user_params` definition is better practice.

**EDIT**: Thanks to a helpful friend, I figured out that the issue was actually how I was sending the AJAX call from the frontend. I had it set up like so:

```
axios.post('/users', {
    name: e.target.name.value,
    password: e.target.password.value,
    other_option: e.target.option.value
 }).then((res) => { /* do some stuff */ })
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

when really the object I was sending should have been ...

```
axios.post('/users', {
    user: {
        name: e.target.name.value,
        password: e.target.password.value,
        other_option: e.target.option.value
     }, 
  }).then((res) => { /* do some stuff */ })
   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

... since in ....

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :other_option)
end
```

... it's expecting the request body to have an object `:user`.